# Why there are two versions in specification-version in jar MANIFEST file?

Tags: maven, manifest, ivy

Here is the content of manifest in [ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar from mavencentral](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.1.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.5.0_13-121 ("Apple Computer, Inc.")
Built-By: hibernate.org
Specification-Title: EJB 3.0
Specification-Version: 3.0 Final Release (1.0.1.GA)
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: EJB
Implementation-Version: 3.0 Final Release (1.0.1.GA) March 14 2008
Implementation-Vendor: hibernate.org
```

Why there are two versions 3.0 Final Release and 1.0.1.GA in each of Specification-Version and Implementation-Version?

Also, the same jar file is called ejb3-persistence-3.3.1.jar in our ivy repository, I ended up searching version 3.3.1 and realized [ejb3-persistence-3.3.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ejb3/ejb3-persistence-3.3.1.jar.zip) and [ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.1.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar) have the same manifest file.

It is confusing, there are three versions referring to the same jar file: 3.3.1, 3.0 Final Release and 1.0.0.GA.

Answer (score 0):

`3.0 Final Release` is the version of the EJB specification [JSR 220](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220); `1.0.1.GA` is the version of Java Persistence API (JPA), which was originally part of the same JSR; JPA 2 has its own [JSR](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317). I suspect that `3.3.1` comes from the version of Hibernate that you are using. [This page](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-1709?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3afisheye-issuepanel) contains some more information about the differences between the 1.0.0.GA and 1.0.1.GA versions of the `ej3-persistence` JAR